# How can I safely quote third party's content?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

Quoting is a very common practice among academics. You copy a piece of someone else's work and attribute the proper credit. But the problem is doing it online, since it could be perceived as duplicate content which is bad for SEO. After searching for a while I've found some claims that Google is very secretive about its methods. Does anyone know how I can safely have quotes in my website and let Google know it's a quote?

Comment: Just place a link to the original source, then search engines can recognize what the relation between your site and the original site is (you are referring to the other site but the other site not to yours).

Answer (score 3):

Content is made up of two things -- the *literal text* and the *context*. Since the context is different, it's not duplicate content. Provided you are properly citing a third party, there will be no problem. If your content is of value, then you do not need to worry.

You can markup a quote in a way similar to the following:

```
<blockquote>
    <p>This is the text you are quoting</p>
</blockquote>
<p>&mdash; <cite>Work you are quoting</cite>, Author Name, Date...</p>
```

Comment: And <q> for shorter quotes. There's a *really* detailed look at the semantics here: http://html5doctor.com/blockquote-q-cite/

Comment: Is this format rigid? I was wondering if simple quotation marks followed by the cited work would suffice or a simple link if the original was posted online.

Comment: From a semantic point of view, you would either need to use `blockquote` or `q` -- that will essentially place quotation marks around your quote. I wouldn't know regarding Google's interpretation.

Comment: Here is a Google webmaster video on this exact subject: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hy3_Rjc0Tso